# the meaning of "Crosbian"

Tags: meaning

> Crosbian Nihilistic Reading of Sadegh Hedayat’s Three Drops of Blood and Franz Kafka’s The Trial

(source: [Modern Journal of Studies in English Language Teaching and Literature](https://www.mjselt.com/iefl-journals/iefl-2013/crosbian-nihilistic-reading-of-sadegh-hedayat-s-three-drops-of-blood-and-franz-kafka-s-the-trial/))

I'm at my wits' end with understanding the adjective "Crosbian" in the context of my passage. Is it related to some literary scholar Crosby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found what appears to be the actual paper referred to, at [Semantic Scholar](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/72f1/d5cfe33be29cf2bb457c102bfbec1c56df61.pdf). Reading the first page, I see a paragraph that begins

> This article contains the necessary definitions and assumptions for the study, and is primarily based on the first two chapters of Donald A. Crosby’s *The Specter of the Absurd: Sources and criticisms of Modern Nihilism* (1988). Crosby’s book ...

I thus conclude that “crosbian” in the title essentially means “after the fashion of Donald A. Crosby”.

Comment: The word Crosbian should be capitalised, as it is a 'proper adjective' (i.e. derived from a proper noun, as are Victorian, Dickensian, Trumpian, American, etc). If the OP had not encountered it at the start of a title, where it should be capitalised in any case, then he/she might have realised sooner that it refers to a person called Crosby, or Crosb-_something_.  Reading the paper would have led to Donald A Crosby.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a reference to [Donald A. Crosby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_A._Crosby), who according to the linked article wrote a

> book on philosophical nihilism, The Specter of the Absurd, published in 1988